# Force Infopath formatting rules to recalculate with C# codebehind

Tags: c#, formatting, refresh, code-behind, infopath

I'm aware of the `this.CurrentView.ForceUpdate();` function which synchronizes the underlying XML with the current form view, but it does ***not*** seem to cause any formatting or validation rules to refresh themselves.

I have some code set up to remove a signature on a button press, and that works successfully, but all formatting rules that depended on that signable section being "signed" don't update themselves, even after a `ForceUpdate()`.

The rules *are* updated, however, if I open up the digital signatures dialog in InfoPath, and then immediately close it. At that point, all rules recalculate and accurately reflect the current state of the form.

Comment: what happens after you immediately close it..? can you also step through your code using the debugger..?

Comment: When I open the Digital Signature dialog through InfoPath's form options menu, and then close it without taking any action, this triggers the rules around my digital signatures to be recalculated.

Comment: I'm using the VSTA C# environment that comes packaged with Office for doing code-behind dev for the Office applications. I can step through *my* code, but the Digital Signatures dialog box is not under my "jurisdiction" so to speak, so I can't see what's going on behind there.